# How to download image from Azure Blob into XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, azure, visual-studio-2015

I have an PUBLIC Azure Blob storage container that I am trying to pull down a .jpg file from and display it on a XAML control on my interface. Here is my code so far:

```
/* HANDLING A PICTURE */

// Setting up blob URI here
Uri bloburi2 = new Uri("https://FAKE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/TEST.jpg");
// Creating new CloudBlockBlob object (passing blob URI as param)
CloudBlockBlob picBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(bloburi);

/***** WAITING FOR MORE ******/
```

What is the best approach to do this? I have seen several examples of Images being pulled down and saved to the user's machine but I have no idea how to get it to display on an Image XAML control.

**UPDATE: Trying to change Image source on c# to blob URI.**

```
image.Source = https://FAKE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/TEST.jpg;
```

Getting errors. Visual Studio is expecting a ';' and a '}' after this statement. My guess is that the URL is confusing the compiler. Putting URL in double quotes not an option since VS takes it as a string and shows error. Any workarounds? Adding pic on XAML is not that viable because I want to modify content as my app goes along...

**SOLVED: Code below**

```
image.Source = new BitmapImage(URI_HERE);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you don't have any security on your blob you can just load the image in an Image control

```
<Image Source="https://FAKE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/TEST.jpg"/>
```

Update:

If you need to set the the image from code, you need to use a BitmapImage that you can initialize with the Uri you have

```
   var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("https://FAKE_NAME.blob.core.windows.net/CONTAINER/TEST.jpg"));
   _image.Source = bi;
```

Comment: thanks for the -1. Would appreciate a comment as to why

Comment: Oh I didn't do that. Just checked your comment. One sec let me try.

Comment: It works! But I still have one more lingering question. Your answer works if I type it on XAML, but if I go into the .cs file and do: image.source = "blobURI"; I get an error saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to Windows.UI.XAML.Media.ImageSource...... Should that work? @AlexDrenea

Comment: Apologies for that -1, I have no idea where that came from, please help me out here!!!

Comment: Added an update, any ideas/tips would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @ananhalz - I know you didn't -1 my answer. It's OK. you can see my updated answer with the solution to do it from code.

Comment: Yeah, finally got it solved. Thanks a lot!